# Starting out Silverlight 4 design

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface, silverlight-4.0

I come from mainly a web development background (ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, XHTML, CSS etc) but have been tasked with creating/designing a Silverlight application.  The application is utilising Bing Maps control for Silverlight, this will be contained in a user control and will be the 'main' screen in the system.

There will be numerous other user controls on the form that will be used to choose/filter/sort/order the data on the map.  I think of it like Visual Studio: the Bing Maps will be like the code editor window and the other controls will be like Solutions Explorer, Find Results etc. (although a lot less of them!)

I have read up and I'm comfortable with the data side (RIA-Services) of the application.  I've (kinda) got my head around databinding and using a view model to present data and keep the code behind file lite.

What I do need some help on is UI design/navigation framework, specifically 2 aspects:

- How do I best implement a fluid design so that the various user controls which filter the map data can be resized/pinned/unpinned (for example, like the Solution Explorer in VS)? I made a test using a Grid with a GridSplitter control, is this the best way?  Would it be best to create a Grid/Gridsplitter with Navigation Frames inside the grid to load the content?
- Since I have multiple user controls that basically use the same set of data, should I set the dataContext at the highest possible level (e.g. if using a grid with multiple frames, at the Grid level?).

Any help, tips, links etc. will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has created a great community site for helping people get started with both design and Silverlight here: http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/

It may be far more than what you need for your current project, but it definitely will give you the training you need to master Design with Silverlight.